# Why my Preoder, Inorder and Postorder functions are not working

Tags: binary-tree, recursive-datastructures, inorder, preorder, postorder

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

#### Node Creation

This structure creates the struct node data type

```
 struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *left, *right;
    } * newnode;
```

#### Create Function

`create()` - It first allocates the memory required for the node. When user enters the data, it recursively calls itself to create its child node, and this process goes on. When the user enters -1, it terminates the recursion and goes back from where it is called.

```
    struct node *create()
    {
        int x;
        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->left = 0;
        newnode->right = 0;
        printf("Enter data(-1 for no node)\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x == -1)
            return 0;
        newnode->data = x;
        printf("Enter left child of %d\n", x);
        newnode->left = create();
    
        printf("Enter right child of %d\n", x);
        newnode->right = create();
        return newnode;
    }
```

#### Preorder

`preorder(struct node *root)` - This function displays the data of the tree in preorder manner

```
    void preorder(struct node *root)
    {
        if (root == 0)
            return;
    
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
```

#### Inorder

`inorder(struct node *root)` - This function displays the data of the tree in inorder manner

```
    void inorder(struct node *root)
    {
        if (root == 0)
            return;
    
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
```

#### Postorder

`Postorder(struct node *root)` - This function displays the data of the tree in postorder manner

```
    void postorder(struct node *root)
    {
        if (root == 0)
            return;
    
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
    }
```

#### Main Function

Main function asks the user to create a tree and then traverse it according to the choice entered by the user. The problem is that preorder, inorder and postorder are not giving the required output, and result in an infinite loop after execution.

```
 void main()
    {
        struct node *root;
        root = 0;
        int choice = 3, opt = 1;
    
        while (opt)
        {
            printf("Select\n 1-for creation\n 2-for preorder\n 3-for inorder\n 4-for postorder\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                root = create();
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Preorder is: ");
                preorder(root);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Inorder is: ");
                inorder(root);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Postorder is: ");
                postorder(root);
                break;
    
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice");
                break;
            }
            printf("Wanna continue \n1-for yes\n0-for no\n");
            scanf("%d", &opt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bug with any of the traversal functions you've provided.
No design or implementation problem with `create ()` function either.

The trouble lies in the global `struct node` pointer `newnode` declared with the structure's definition.

Because each recursive call to `create ()` is basically using the "same" `newnode` pointer, the tree is never really built in the way we want it to.

Let's try to dry run the `create ()` function.

Let's say we want a tree like this:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

1. `create ()` is first called from `main`.

- The memory is allocated using `malloc ()` function and the address of the memory is stored in `newnode`.
- Set it's attributes, `left` and `right`.
- Ask for `data` and put it into `data` attribute, if `data == -1` is true, `return 0`.

Up until this point, this is the state:

```
newnode -> 1
          / \
       Null  Null
```

2. `create ()` is recursively called to build the left subtree.

- The memory is allocated for `newnode` using `malloc ()` and the address of the memory is stored in `newnode`. Note that this operation has basically "**over-wrote**" the address previously stored in `newnode` (because `newnode` is a **global variable**)
- Then again, the user will be prompted for the `data` and its attributes will be set.

Therefore, the tree has now become:

```
newnode -> 2
          / \
       Null  Null
```

The `struct node` to which `newnode` was previously pointing is now lost (because of loss of its address)

Similarly, when the recursive call for the right subtree is made, then, the following will be observed:

```
newnode -> 3
          / \
       Null  Null
```

Considering the same scenario for the rest of the recursive calls made, it is clear that in the end, the tree we were expecting wasn't built and the reason is the **global variable** `newnode`, the constant allocation of memory and over-writing the address in `newnode` led to **memory leakage** only.

The reason infinite recursion was found is that, during multiple recursive calls, the `left` or `right` pointer of `newnode` was made to point to `newnode` itself, leading to a cycle. This node can be found by closely tracking the `data` of `newnode` during the recursive calls.

Hence, remove the declaration of `newnode` pointer from the structure declaration and modify the following statement in `create ()` function:

`newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

to this:

`struct node * newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

And

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};
```

is all what's needed.

In this way, each recursive call to `create ()` function will have its own local pointer variable `newnode` and there will be no overwriting, no leakage, no cycle, no infinite recursion.